# Test automation-slow motion

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, testing, automated-tests

Is there any concrete way to make an automation test that is testing a web page progress in slow motion?not keeping the page up for a long amount of time, but actually running the simulation in slow motion?

Comment: what do you mean by slow motion , I did not get it.

Comment: What do you mean? It sounds like you want the browser to load slowly, i.e. throttling your network?

Comment: like I want each test to run through navigation through a webpage slow just for show.Is there any code for this?My tests simulate pretty fast.There's no way you can slow them down?

Answer (score 2):

You can try implicit wait time to check your result on each action/statement. 
[(Explicit and Implicit Waits)](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

```
//3 second implicit wait (JAVA code)
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```